# How to rotate an object using local coordinates

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't find how to rotate an object around it's local coordinates, I tried using the rotation property, but it rotates the object around the world axis. I also tried to displace the object, set it at position (0,0,0), then rotate it and put it back where it was, but it doesn't work.

I don't find a way, any suggest?

Comment: Can you provide some code or jsFiddle example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/theo/VsWb9/) working code.

```
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene.add(camera);

    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function render() {

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Comment: The example works just because the object is in the world system origin.

Comment: Updated  http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/1567/ , not in the center now

Comment: My mistake, I was rotating an object loaded from a json model that had a different coordinate system.